# robust haskell interpreter on android

Tags: android, haskell, interpreter

I have been tinkering with the development of a compiler written in haskell, and I'd like to do so on my 'droid.  Now I know I probably can't get a full-fledged, cabal-capable development environment, but an interpreter that does datatypes, type classes,  and primitive file io doesn't seem like too much to ask (or does it?).  Can anybody relate their experiences doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android isn't suited for programming, development or any kind of productive work. One can use it for browsing kitty-cat photos on web, but any other tasks will be extremely awkward. If you don't trust me and still want this, just try using ideone.com -- it's the online compiler supporting haskell.

Comment: and there is the fpcomplete online ide - I guess it serves the same needs

Comment: With a rooted device you get CLI, which should allow you to run some tiling WM, Vim and full GHC; That looks alright for me.

Comment: I think it should be possible to get full GHC on an ARM platform, but I also agree with user2894391 that Android is bound to become awkward for any development stuff. Do consider e.g. [Ubuntu Phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone) instead.